# The name 'Model' dose not exists in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view, when i render a partial view

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("InnerView/_lstCars", Tuple.Create(Model.lstMyData, Model.FirstAllow, Model.SecondAllow, Model.ThirdAllow));}
```

in the inner view _lstCars i receive

```
@model Tuple<List<lstMyDTO>, bool, bool, bool>
```

when i try to add the fourthAllow :

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("InnerView/_lstCars", Tuple.Create(Model.lstMyData, Model.FirstAllow, Model.SecondAllow, Model.ThirdAllow,Model.fourthAllow));}

@model Tuple<List<lstMyDTO>, bool, bool, bool,bool>
```

i got the error:

> The name 'Model' dose not exists in the current context.

i'm cleaned the solution , did a rebuild , close and reopen the visual studio but the error 
still appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `Model.fourthAllow` is bool type or not.

If the `@model Tuple<List<lstMyDTO>, bool, bool, bool>` works, but failed when adding the `Model.fourthAllow`.

These type parameters must be same as `@mode` you declare, so that you can get your Model in the view.

```
Tuple.Create(Model.lstMyData, Model.FirstAllow, Model.SecondAllow, Model.ThirdAllow,Model.fourthAllow))

@model Tuple<List<lstMyDTO>, bool, bool, bool,bool>
```